# Rails 3.0.3 Getting Started Guide code doesn't display field_with_errors div for the Tag field (first post)

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, css, ruby

I read and copy/pasted the entire Ruby on Rails 3 Getting Started guide blog example application. I got a working blog application running. I added some validation code to the Post model as follows:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :name,  :length => { :maximum => 64 }

  validates :title, :presence => true,
            :length => { :minimum => 5 }

  validates :content, :presence => true,
            :length => { :minimum => 5 }

  validates :tags, :presence => true,
            :length => { :minimum => 1 }

  has_many  :comments, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many  :tags

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :tags, :allow_destroy => :true,
            :reject_if => proc { |attrs| attrs.all? { |k, v| v.blank? } }
end
```

When I try to submit an empty form to test the validation code I get the expected errors, but it doesn't display the `<div class="field_with_errors">` div for the Tag field.

The resulting HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Rails Blog</title>
  <link href="/stylesheets/scaffold.css?1292045851" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <script src="/javascripts/prototype.js?1292044228" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="/javascripts/effects.js?1292044228" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="/javascripts/dragdrop.js?1292044228" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="/javascripts/controls.js?1292044228" type="text/javascript"></script>

  <script src="/javascripts/rails.js?1292044229" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="/javascripts/application.js?1292044228" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <meta name="csrf-param" content="authenticity_token"/>
  <meta name="csrf-token" content="FYDsbSpjAry7CQrVbdgdozsOJ66w4f4b8nVQ+towSYg="/>
</head>
<body>

<h1>New post</h1>

<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/posts" class="new_post" id="new_post" method="post"><div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" /><input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="FYDsbSpjAry7CQrVbdgdozsOJ66w4f4b8nVQ+towSYg=" /></div>
  <div id="errorExplanation">
    <h2>6 errors prohibited this post from being saved:</h2>

    <ul>
      <li>Title can't be blank</li>
      <li>Title is too short (minimum is 5 characters)</li>
      <li>Content can't be blank</li>
      <li>Content is too short (minimum is 5 characters)</li>
      <li>Tags can't be blank</li>

      <li>Tags is too short (minimum is 1 characters)</li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <label for="post_name">Name</label><br />
    <input id="post_name" name="post[name]" size="30" type="text" value="" />
  </div>
  <div class="field">

    <div class="field_with_errors"><label for="post_title">Title</label></div><br />
    <div class="field_with_errors"><input id="post_title" name="post[title]" size="30" type="text" value="" /></div>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <div class="field_with_errors"><label for="post_content">Content</label></div><br />
    <div class="field_with_errors"><textarea cols="40" id="post_content" name="post[content]" rows="20"></textarea></div>
  </div>

  <h2>Tags</h2>

  <div class="field">
    <label for="post_tags_attributes_0_name">Tag:</label>
    <input id="post_tags_attributes_0_name" name="post[tags_attributes][0][name]" size="30" type="text" />
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <input id="post_submit" name="commit" type="submit" value="Create Post" />

  </div>
</form>

<a href="/posts">Back</a>


</body>
</html>
```

What might be causing the `<div class="field_with_errors">` absence? Does it have anything to do with the tag form being in a partial? Thanks for reading my first post.

posts/_form.html.erb:

```
<% @post.tags.build %>
<%= form_for(@post) do |post_form| %>
  <% if @post.errors.any? %>
  <div id="errorExplanation">
    <h2><%= pluralize(@post.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this post from being saved:</h2>
    <ul>
    <% @post.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
      <li><%= msg %></li>
    <% end %>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= post_form.label :name %><br />
    <%= post_form.text_field :name %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= post_form.label :title %><br />
    <%= post_form.text_field :title %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= post_form.label :content %><br />
    <%= post_form.text_area :content %>
  </div>
  <h2>Tags</h2>
  <%= render :partial => 'tags/form',
             :locals => {:form => post_form} %>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= post_form.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

tags/_form.html.erb:

```
<%= form.fields_for :tags do |tag_form| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= tag_form.label :name, 'Tag:' %>
    <%= tag_form.text_field :name %>
  </div>
  <% unless tag_form.object.nil? || tag_form.object.new_record? %>
    <div class="field">
      <%= tag_form.label :_destroy, 'Remove:' %>
      <%= tag_form.check_box :_destroy %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

The command terminal output when the blank form is submitted:

```
Started POST "/posts" for 192.168.11.28 at 2010-12-11 23:23:03 +0000
  Processing by PostsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"T2o6Tn8cfeJyVVcFMU91Zuk42BBs06uqyMIgfmy41SM=", "post"=>{"name"=>"", "title"=>"", "content"=>"", "tags_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"name"=>""}}}, "commit"=>"Create Post"}
Rendered tags/_form.html.erb (45.5ms)
Rendered posts/_form.html.erb (320.0ms)
Rendered posts/new.html.erb within layouts/application (351.2ms)
Completed 200 OK in 748ms (Views: 379.2ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

Comment: can you please post your form partial ruby code.

Comment: Do you actually get the validation errors for the blank tags or do they just not get saved?

Comment: When I try to submit a blank form it says `Tags can't be blank` and
`Tags is too short (minimum is 1 characters)` and the command line output is added to the post above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you added `attr_accessible` in your `Post` class:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
    ....
    attr_accessible :tag_attributes 
    # or it could be the plural version :tags_attributes
    ....
end
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I tried `attr_accessible :name, :title, :content, :tags_attributes` and `attr_accessible :tags_attributes`. The first one allows me to create posts while the other does not. I get a mass assignment warning if I use `tag_attributes` or `post_tags_attributes`. Sadly the `attr_accessible :name, :title, :content, :tags_attributes` still doesn't resolve the problem with the field_with_errors div class.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure how the `field_with_errors` magic works but it appears to require a label or input for the field failing validation. So if you add a `post_form.label :tags` that will trigger it. But it is not appearing for the name text_field (or label) on tags because the tag name field isn't failing validation. If you wanted you could add a `field_with_errors` div yourself after checking `@post.errors[:tags].empty?`.

Answer (score 0):

I think I see a couple of things, but I'm not positive about either of them. First, I don't think you can use validates :tags directly if #tags is an association rather than an attribute. That should be validates_associated :tags (and then validates_presence_of :name in the Tag model).

Second, isn't the :reject_if option of accept_nested_attributes_for going to get triggered if you submit a blank form? If that happens, your Tag object is going to get obliterated before the form is rendered.